# Taming feral cats

Tags: cats, feral

How do I earn the trust of a feral cat? I do not have meat or cat food, what can I feed them? Should I try to touch them or let them come for me? I have never seen kittens of 1-10 weeks old, where do they live?

Comment: If you lack meat AND cat food (and have no sources for either?), you can try feeding cooked eggs. Eggs are fine as an additional food, not a sole food, but for ferals, they are certainly a tasty and trust-building addition.

Comment: How old is the cat you're trying to tame? Are you just trying to be friendly with a cat who will live outdoors or bring it indoors? I'm going to mark this a duplicate until you provide more information (then we can open it back up).

Comment: @Layna  what kind of eggs? boiled, scrambled?

Comment: @Zaralynda i want to have a cat as a pet or maybe a dog. but i dont see kittens much, i only see grown up cats. where do kittens live?

Comment: The eggs realyl should just be cooked. Peel them, breka them open, and then offer them. The cats SHOULD go for them, being feral and most likely not too choosy about food :).

Comment: @Zaralynda cooked means? Just break egg open and mix it and offer or something else. sorry

Comment: cooked = apply heat (either to the insides in a pan, or to the unopened egg in a pot of water)

Comment: It's pretty difficult to tell what exactly you're asking here, you've got several different questions. Perhaps a good place to start would be deciding if you want a cat or dog, and then focus on finding out how to get one